# xampp and virtual hosts not working properly

Tags: xampp

my virtual host setup looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
     <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:8080>
     ServerName mysite.site
     DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\public">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

and the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost 
127.0.0.1     mysite.site
```

but it actually doens't work. I have to go through `localhost/mysite/public` to make it work. Why? Instead of getting my site it loads my localhost default site which is xampp's htdocs folder.

EDIT:
Just wanted to add that I have `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in httpd.conf already.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i finally got this. Looks like my port was incorrect. I checked what port is used in `httpd.conf` under `ServerName localhost:80`. Then I fixed my virtual host setup:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mysite.site
     DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "D:/xampp\htdocs/mysite/public/">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Now it works. :)